# scala unit tests cannot find opencv

Tags: scala, maven, opencv, unsatisfiedlinkerror

The following tells me that the loader can find the opencv library, which is on the loaders path.

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep opencv | grep java
...
libopencv_java330.so -> libopencv_java330.so
```

I am also telling my maven project to use the surefire library, and I am setting the argLine in the following manner:

```
<plugin>                                                          
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>                   
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>                
    <configuration>                                               
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>                                              
        <argLine>
            "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/"
        </argLine>
    </configuration>                                              
</plugin>
```

Also the command

```
$ find /usr/lib/ -name *opencv* | grep java
```

/usr/lib/libopencv_java330.so

Indicates that the library is there. However, when I run `mvn clean test` I get the following output:

```
com.company.package.MyClass  Time elapsed: 0.065 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java330 in java.library.path
```

What do I need to change to get maven to find the native dynamic library?